# Using clangs scan-build with bjam and Boost.Build

Tags: clang, bjam, boost-build, scan-build

Is it possible to use clangs static analyser scan-build in combination with bjam and Boost.Build? I tried to run

```
scan-build bjam
```

which does not work. scan-build reports that the reporting directory does not contain any reports.

Answer (score 1):

This post might be old, but it crops up a lot when I search trying to bottom this, so hopefully this will help someone else:

```
import os ;
using gcc : : [ os.environ CXX ] ;
```

It's just a little tweak in Jamroot.jam to make bjam use the environment variables set by scan-build. I suspect it'll fail for many cases, but it might be enough to get anyone started to something they can work with.